# An outer-space riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme, outer-space

> Twinkle twinkle little star
>
> How I wonder what you are
>
> In the sky just passing by
>
> You can vanish in the blink of an eye
>
> Moving at speeds I can't believe
>
> All the things you can achieve
>
> In an atmosphere you will burn
>
> Luckily you always make the turn
>
> My shift is over so I am out(ter space)
>
> You'll get this easy without a doubt!

This is just something fun I wanted to put together for the new tag, not meant to be a brain buster or anything!

**P.S. The last two lines are not part of the riddle, you can ignore those when thinking**

Comment: Hey, maybe a more descriptive title would help, there is going be lots of outer-space riddles incoming now that it is a topic challenge.

Comment: It looks a tiny bit like an acrostic, but then again it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to try and come up with a clever title, but I wasn't sticking around work any longer. My creative juices were running low as is. Haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> the International Space Station (ISS)?

Edit - a few more details explaining the answer:

> The ISS really does pass by to the naked eye, it travels at [a few miles per second](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=how%20fast%20is%20the%20ISS%20going), the astronauts aboard the ISS get tons of science done and, like anything that orbits, it is always falling (or "turning") to keep the same distance from the earth as it flies along.

Comment: Very well done! I figured someone would get sooner than later.

Answer (score 2):

> Would you be a comet seen from Earth?   I'd explain in detail but it's rather self explanatory, a comet fits every clue. Nice rhymes :)
>
> Comets can be perceived as shooting stars (twinkle twinkle little star), which aren't always visible to the naked eye very long (in the sky obviously). Comets are **very** fast, and travel incredible distances. When they pass close to the sun or too close to planets' atmospheres, they'll burn up somewhat. Some comets have periodic orbits in our solar system so once they've finished their 'pass', they head outwards towards the kuiper belt and oort cloud before coming back etc...   Any quick wiki search will tell you pretty much all you want to know on comets :)

Comment: I'm glad you guessed this actually! I was hoping my riddle skills were getting better. Deception seems to be key to good riddle!

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> A supernova?

Twinkle twinkle little star

How I wonder what you are

In the sky just passing by

> Before going supernova the star "moves across the sky" as the earth rotates/orbits.

You can vanish in the blink of an eye

> Once a start has gone supernova it vanishes from the sky.

Moving at speeds I can't believe

> Either a reference to the velocity of the star itself, or the rate of collapse.

All the things you can achieve

> From the remnants of a supernova new stars can form.

In an atmosphere you will burn

> Self explanatory.

Luckily you always make the turn

> Not too sure about this one.